# Overfull boxes in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, urls, overfull

I get overfull hboxes of urls in my bibliography, also the urls don't work even though they are correct. I can't find the problem. I am grateful for any help as it is urgent.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[skip=9pt,indent=30pt]{parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, top=2.8cm, right=3cm, bottom=2cm,includefoot,head=18pt]{geometry}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion,final]{microtype}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear, autocite=inline,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Masterarbeit.bib}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2060}{\nolinebreak}

\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4} %Spaltenhöhe einstellen

\begin{document}

\autocite{authoryear}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here an example of bibliography entry:

```
@misc{LWK2006,
author = {LWK},
publisher = {Landwirtschaftskammer Rheinland-Pfalz},
file = {:home/leonie/Dokumente/Studium/Weinbau{\&}Oenologie/04{\_}Masterarbeit/02{\_}Literatur/03{\_}Methoden/QWP{\_}Untersuchungsverfahren-FT-IR-Spektrometrie.pdf:pdf},
title = {{Untersuchungsverfahren zur Bestimmung von Vorhandenem Alkohol, Reduzierendem Zucker und Gesamts{\"{a}}ure mittels FT-IR-Spektrometriebei der amtlichen Qualit{\"{a}}tsweinuntersuchung Version}},
url = {https://www.lwk-rlp.de/fileadmin/lwk-rlp.de/Weinbau/PDF/QWP{\_}Untersuchungsverfahren-FT-IR-Spektrometrie.pdf},
urldate = {2023-12-05},
volume = {2},
year = {2006}
}
```

Comment: Don't escape the `_` in the url: `url = {https://www.lwk-rlp.de/fileadmin/lwk-rlp.de/Weinbau/PDF/QWP_Untersuchungsverfahren-FT-IR-Spektrometrie.pdf},`

Comment: For your specific case this also avoids the overfull box: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuZbY.png For a more general solution, you can load the `xurl` package.

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't escape the `_` in the url. This will not only make the link work, but in your specific case also avoid the overfull box warning.

For a more general approach to avoid overfull boxed in the bibliography, you could load the `xurl` package, which will allow more possible breaks points for line breaks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[skip=9pt,indent=30pt]{parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, top=2.8cm, right=3cm, bottom=2cm,includefoot,head=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear, autocite=inline,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.bib}
@misc{LWK2006,
author = {LWK},
publisher = {Landwirtschaftskammer Rheinland-Pfalz},
title = {{Untersuchungsverfahren zur Bestimmung von Vorhandenem Alkohol, Reduzierendem Zucker und Gesamts{\"{a}}ure mittels FT-IR-Spektrometriebei der amtlichen Qualit{\"{a}}tsweinuntersuchung Version}},
url = {https://www.lwk-rlp.de/fileadmin/lwk-rlp.de/Weinbau/PDF/QWP_Untersuchungsverfahren-FT-IR-Spektrometrie.pdf},
urldate = {2023-12-05},
volume = {2},
year = {2006}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{test.bib}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}

%\usepackage{xurl}% <- uncomment to allow more line breaks in url

\begin{document}

\autocite{LWK2006}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works. Thank you!!

Comment: @LeonieWagner You're welcome!